# Unable to use if statement before for loop in List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

```
my_list = []
for x in range(1,50):
    if x%3==0:
        my_list.append(x)
    else:
        pass
print(my_list)
```

```
[x for x in range(1,50) if x%3==0]
```

## Above mentioned both codes are working fine. but the below code is giving me error.

```
[x if x%3==0 else pass for x in range(1,50)]

Error:
File "", line 1
    [x if x%3==0 else pass for x in range(1,50)]
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> But according to the syntax of List Comprehension if we are using "if" before "for" then it should be a complete "if-else" statement

According to my knowledge, all 3 codes should yield same output. Can anyone help me in understanding why I'm getting this error?

I tried executing this code in Python-3.7.4 version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No, this one isn't a duplicate of that, either. They're not asking how to do it. This question even already includes a working list comp with if clause. They're asking why their attempt with `pass` doesn't work.

Comment: @KellyBundy Fine, **you** find it. A question with 103 views and a -1 score, that needs editing and wasn't created artificially to have a canonical, isn't going to be our canonical for this. I'm going to sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pass` is a statement, not an expression, so you can't use it in a list comprehension.

Your first version, as you noted, works fine and is the right way to filter a list in a comprehension, so I'm not sure why you are looking to make it work with the incorrect syntax.

To be more explicit, if you were to replace `pass` by a valid expression, eg:

```
[x if x%3==0 else 0 for x in range(1,50)]
```

then this wouldn't raise any errors. It just wouldn't do what I think you want, as all the non-multiples of 3 would have become `0`, rather than having been excluded. But that's how list comprehensions (and `map` and `filter`, which are equivalent) work: something of the form `[expr(x) for x in lst]` will always have exactly the same length as `lst`, and in order to filter using an `if` statement you need the `if` clause *after* the `for`, as in your first, working, example.